# How to get started with Amazon Product Advertising API C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm doing this for the first time so I'm very new to this API.
I need to write a C# program to fetch products by keywords, just like performing an item search on Amazon.
I just started investigating on the `ItemSearch` API using these links:

- [Item Search](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html)
- [Search By Keyword](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_SearchingbyKeyword.html)

But I can't find any relevant code samples since the most recent one is 6 years ago...
I understood that I have to have an "Associate Tag" but in order to do so, I need to provide a website URL which I currently don't have since I just started coding.

Do I have to have an "Associate Tag" right from the start in order to start developing ?

Are there any recent and relevant C# code samples ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this sample project in Git which can be found here: [jz5/AmazonProductAdvtApiSample-2013](https://github.com/jz5/AmazonProductAdvtApiSample-2013)

It has a good base which one can build on, so I hope it may come in handy to other users as well.

Answer (score 1):

A current project to this assignment you can found here https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising

The library is also available over nuget

```
PM> install-package Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising
```

Example:

```
var authentication = new AmazonAuthentication();
authentication.AccessKey = "accesskey";
authentication.SecretKey = "secretkey";

var wrapper = new AmazonWrapper(authentication, AmazonEndpoint.US);
var result = wrapper.Search("canon eos", AmazonSearchIndex.Electronics, AmazonResponseGroup.Large);
```

Comment: above code return null for me. Can you please help me?

Comment: Check the output of this two events `wrapper.XmlReceived += (xml) => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(xml); };
wrapper.ErrorReceived += (errorResonse) => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(errorResonse.Error.Message); };`